# How to Remove Cookies in RESPONSE Body of REST service

Tags: java, cookies

Where to Add the below code in my Java(Middleware between UI and Business Implementation) project to stop caching in UI.

**Java code:**

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies
```

Comment: You should write it in a Java class just before writing the response to OutputStream

Comment: I have thousands of method written and i have a lot of java class. i donot know where to add.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd write a filter that sets those headers.

```
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    res.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); // Proxies.

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}


public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

}

}
```

And add it to your web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter </filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.NoCacheFilter </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter </filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I've set the filter to the `rest` url context. This assumes the REST services are on a single context.